# How to plot a 100 variables paired t test and correlation matrix

Tags: data-visualization, paired-data

I have more than 100 variables from a biological data for which I have values for before and after surgery. I am doing two analysis:

1. A paired t test for before and after measurements.
2. A correlation matrix for these 100 variables for just "before Surgery" data.

I need some advice to plot the results of above two analysis. I tried correlogram for the correlation matrix. But its not very good visualization for a 100 x 100 matrix. Can we use volcano plot for paired t tests?

Comment: You should really tell us some more context! So you have 100 paired t tests? You could try 100 Tukey mean-difference plots (Bland-Altman plots). Some more context will help!

Comment: Hi, My data has more than 100 features which are measured for more than 50 patients before and after surgery. So I will have 100 paired t tests. Is there a way to plot this 100 t tests in one plot.

I also want to do a correlation matrix for this 100 features (with measurements before surgery) What is the best way to plot 100 x 100 correlation matrix? 

I have a sample data here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bwfS8EdU6nYTEUOJTz49unlUe00SB56G/view?usp=sharing